# How to format USB stick to exfat in Ubuntu 18.04 (now with kernel 5.3.0-42)?

Tags: partitioning, mount, exfat

This is a dual boot laptop HP 8570p with Ubuntu 18.04 and Win 10. I've installed exfat-fuse and exfat-utils (both are of version 1.2.8-1 and they are now located in directory: /dev/sda5/usr/share/doc in form of changelog.Debian.gz), Ubuntu is in this /dev/sda5 device.

I tried to mount exfat using terminal two commands: 
1.) at first 'mount exfat usr/share/doc', but the reply was: 'mount: only root can do that'; 
2.) and secondly 'sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sda5/usr/share/doc  /media/exfat, but the reply was: 
'FUSE exfat 1.2.8 
ERROR: failed to open '/dev/sda5/usr/share/doc': Not a directory.'

How can I proceed with mounting correctly ?

After this I tried to format USB stick to exFat with GParted, but my GParted (vers 0.30.3) does not support exFat. Can I do something to make my GParted to support also exFat ?

Comment: Thanks for advices. Terminal says I installed exfat files correctly,  but somehow I cannot neither mount exfat with those commands I indicated, though I think the commands are correct, nor get GParted to support also exFat. Should I just wait until exfat will be part of Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: `changelog.Debian.gz‍‍` does not look like the right version for Ubuntu. Neither does it look like any installed software. You may want to follow the answers in the above link and try installing again.

Comment: After sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse I've had this reply all the way before I made this question:         
exfat-fuse is already in latest version (1.2.8-1).
exfat-utils is already in latest version (1.2.8-1). Meaning I can read and write USB formated with exfat. My problem is how to command GParted to format empty USB with exfat. In discussions of the provided link in 2013 this was not possible, but is it now possible ? If it is now possible, how ?

Comment: Or, is it possible to use Gparted to re-format USB with fat32 format to USB with exfat format ?

Comment: Using GParted would be OK.

Comment: In my GParted exFat is not supported. With Ubuntu app Tools/Disks it is possible to change Fat32 to NTFS/exFat/HPFS. In Windows 10 exFat is possible to create with AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard (or in terminal of some Win 10, but it /terminal/ could not make it in my Win 10 Pro), pls see https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/exfat-format-windows-10-3889.html.

Comment: Please use `gnome-disks`. It has exfat default included so no need for 3rd party tools.

Comment: @Rinzwind, thank you for advive. I did not know correct name of the tool (gnome-disk), but anyway, yes, it can format USB to NTFS/exFat/HPFS.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this when manullay mounting USB Devices.
Code:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/{usbdevicename} /media/external -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

The options following the "-o" give you ownership of the drive, and the masks allow for extra security for file system permissions. If you don't use those extra options you may not be able to read and write the drive with your regular username. Use the correct location/path instead of `{usbdevicename}`

If you need the correct path you can use:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It will be something like `sdb1`, `sdc1`. The 3rd letter depends on the amount of storage devices in the system.

Comment: Thank you for mounting advice, it worked well.

Comment: I make an edit to this: people do NOT read the whole answer when they see a command. So I removed the sdb1 so it will error out if they do